# How to create a moving image animation to the left or right?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have a question about how to change coordinates of animation image.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<canvas id="img" width="600" height="400" style="border:2px solid black;">
</canvas>
<script>
(function () {  
images = [];

function loop () {
var i;
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i += 1) {
images[i].update();
images[i].render();
}
}
function tampilan(gambar) {
var tampil = {},
indexFrame = 0,
jmlputaran = 0,
putaranPerFrame = gambar.putaranPerFrame || 0,
jmlFrame = gambar.jmlFrame || 1;

tampil.context = gambar.context;
tampil.width = gambar.width;
tampil.height = gambar.height;
tampil.x = 0;
tampil.y = 0;
tampil.image = gambar.image;
tampil.ratio = 1;

tampil.update = function () {
jmlputaran += 1;
if (jmlputaran > putaranPerFrame) {
jmlputaran = 0;
if (indexFrame < jmlFrame - 1) {    
if (indexFrame < jmlFrame - 1) {    
indexFrame += 1;
} 
else 
{
indexFrame = 0;
}
}
};  
tampil.render = function () {

tampil.context.drawImage(
tampil.image,
indexFrame * tampil.width / jmlFrame,
0,
tampil.width / jmlFrame,
tampil.height,
tampil.x,
tampil.y,
tampil.width / jmlFrame * tampil.ratio,
tampil.height * tampil.ratio);
};
tampil.lebarframe = function () {
return tampil.width / jmlFrame;
};
return tampil;
}
function draw () {  
var a,
img;
img = new Image();  
a = images.length;
images[a] = tampilan({
context: canvas.getContext("2d"),
width: 380,
height: 147,
image: img,
jmlFrame:3,
putaranPerFrame: 30,
});
img.src = "image.png";
}
var canvas = document.getElementById("img");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
{
draw();
}
loop();

}());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And for example , i want to make my image moving like this --> www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-quadratic-motion-animation/

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do that with css transitions. here is simple example what you need http://jsbin.com/pivayi/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the co-ordinates of the canvas this way.

You'll need to [download](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js/master/jquery.transform2d.js) and attach the [jquery.transform2d.js](http://louisremi.github.io/jquery.transform.js/) plugin.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n1tgoxuv/)

#### HTML:

```
<canvas id="img"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/the/downloaded/plugin"></script>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("img");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var sticky = new Image();
sticky.src = "http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/3.jpg";
sticky.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(sticky, 0, 0);
};

$('#img').click(function () {
    $('#img').animate({'transform': 'matrix(1,0,0,1,50,50)'});
});
```

To move the image to a co-ordinate (150, 600), you would replace `'matrix(1,0,0,1,50,50)'` with `'matrix(1,0,0,1,150,600)'`